# Test database not keeping data during Django Channels Pytest test

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pytest, django-channels

I'm writing tests for a Django Channels application following the [documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/testing.html). I can successfully test connection and communication with the WebSocket consumer. However, in one of the tests I need to create a user.

This is my test method:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_1():
    my_user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(username='my_user', email='user@user.com', password='123456')
    my_user.save()

    print(User.objects.all())

    communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(MyConsumer, '/websocket/')
    communicator.instance.scope['user'] = my_user
    connected, subprotocol = await communicator.connect()
    assert connected
    await communicator.send_json_to({
        'command': 'test',
    })
    response = await communicator.receive_json_from(timeout=5)
    await communicator.disconnect()
```

The error occurs inside the method that handles the `'command' == 'test'` case. When it tries to save another model instance that has User as a foreign key, the test fails.

```py
client = Client(user=scope['user'])
client.save()
```

If I add a `print(User.objects.all())` to the method inside the consumer (between the previous two lines), it returns an empty QuerySet, while the first `print` in the test method itself returns the created user. Of course, since there is no User, the test fails with:

```py
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "chat_client" violates foreign key constraint "chat_client_user_id_d10928fc_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user".
```

I tried turning user creation into another async method and `await`ing for it, but nothing changed. Why is the `User` table getting emptied during the test's execution? How can I keep data created at the beginning of the test?

Comment: You need to make the test transactional; check out a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136564/django-channels-2-accessing-db-in-tests).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated by @hoefling in the comments, the only thing missing was to make the test transactional, as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136564/django-channels-2-accessing-db-in-tests).

In my case, I only had to change the test decorator to:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
```