# Django channels testing weird database behaviour

Tags: django, django-channels, django-testing, channel

Django/channels newbie: I'm trying to write unit tests for my application, but I'm getting some weird behaviour from tests.
I suspect it has something to do with either asynchronous code or django testing database but I'm lost.

My consumer has this kind of structure:

```
class GameConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['gameID']
        self.room_group_name = 'game_%s' % self.room_name

        # check something from database to decide if this connection should be rejected
        if not await self.does_game_exists():
            await self.close(4001)
        else:
            await self.accept()
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name
            )
            
            # insert data into db
            await self.add_player_to_game()
            

    @database_sync_to_async
    def does_game_exists(self):
        ....

    @database_sync_to_async
    def add_player_to_game(self):
        ....
```

This works when using the application normally; the data is inserted in the db.

Now the unit test:

```
class WSConsumerTest(TransactionTestCase):
    fixtures = ['test-data.yaml']

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_num_players(self):
        ...

    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_test_game(self):
        ...

    async def test_player_is_added_on_successful_connection(self):
        game = await self.create_test_game()

        application = URLRouter([
            url(r'ws/game/(?P<gameID>[a-zA-Z0-9]{6})', consumers.GameConsumer),
        ])

        communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(application, f"/ws/game/{game.gameID}")
        connected, _ = await communicator.connect()

        player_count = await self.get_num_players()
        self.assertEqual(player_count, 1, "Player is not added in database after successful connection")

        communicator.disconnect()
```

This fails. get_num_players returns the number of player in the game instance created by create_test_game. I'm sure this two functions are correct, they are standard django ORM queries.

I tried running test with --keepdb option and the db is empty, not even the test game entry is created.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advice.

### Edit

By modifying the test

```
async def test_player_is_added_on_successful_connection(self):
        game = await self.create_test_game()

        application = URLRouter([
            url(r'ws/game/(?P<gameID>[a-zA-Z0-9]{6})', consumers.GameConsumer),
        ])

        communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(application, f"/ws/game/{game.gameID}")
        connected, _ = await communicator.connect()

        self.assertTrue(connected)

        player_count = await self.get_num_players()
        self.assertEqual(player_count, 1, "Player is not added in database after successful connection")

        communicator.disconnect()
```

the test fails because the connection is rejected. It's rejected because the consumer doesn't find the game entry in the db; but if I search for the game in the database in the test method, the game is found.

Do tests and consumers use different databases?

Comment: It seems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175352/ is related, I suggest anyone facing the same issue to test related solution